# Jackson alternative for deprecated org.apache.sling.commons.json*. .toJsonArray(JSONArray) method

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have some code that converts a JSONObject to a JSONArray using the .toJsonArray(JsonArray Names )

Am trying to find something equivalent in the Jackson library that does the same as the deprecated .toJsonArray(JSONArray names) in the org.apache.sling.commons.json*. library.

Old code :

```
JSONArray testArray = ["one", "two", "three"];

JSONArray jObjectArr = jsonObject.toJsonArray(testArray)
```

Is there a straightforward alternative in the JAckson library ? So far I have tried the following

```
1.      ArrayNode jObjectArr = ((ArrayNode)jsonNode).addAll(testArray);
2.     ArrayNode jObjectArr = ((ObjectNode)jsonNode).arrayNode().addAll(testArray);
3. ArrayNode jObjectArr =  mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, ArrayNode.class);
```

I get a ClassCastException for all of the above.

Comment: The line `JsonArray testArray = ["one", "two", "three"];` in your “old code” is not valid Java code. Not sure your question is answerable like this…

Comment: So, I am trying to replace the deprecated .toJsonArray(JSONArray names) with a suitable alternative from the Jackson library. I believe the .toJsonArray() creates an array using the keys from the passed names parameter. Is there an equivalent method in the Jackson library to do the same? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not as far as I know. But if you have a Java Map you could transform it into the desired Java List and then pass that to jackson…